# Link from an HTML page to a specific page or content in xps file

Tags: html, hyperlink, navigation, anchor, xps

How can I create a link from an HTML page to a specific page or content in xps file like (*.html#anhor, or .pdf#page=2 in pdf)?
Asume you create the xps file first as **save as xps** in the Microsoft Word. How to create in this case an anchor? If it's impossible, how to navigate directly to the desired page or position in the text?

Comment: Programming language? Library? How are you making the XPS file?

Comment: If you are not creating the XPS through code, you probably want to move the question to superuser.com

Comment: If necessarily, I can create a xps through code.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can use a [pack URI](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-shur-pack-uri-scheme-05.txt) to link into specific parts of an XPS document, unfortunately at the moment the major browsers don't support it.

Comment: Is it possible to jump to a specific position in the xps viewer or in an appropriated wpf control (like DocumentViewer)?